# ntp.conf Permission Denied on Pi3

Tags: ntp

I'm having an issue with my new Pi. I picked the starting project of Stratum 2 NTP server.  At a minimum I would like to act as a local NTP server for machines on the LAN.  Per multiple sources online I've tried :

```
/etc/ntp.conf
bash : /etc/ntp.conf : Permission Denied
```

I've also tried:

```
sudo su
/etc/ntp.conf
bash : /etc/ntp.conf : Permission Denied
```

It hasn't been a very good start.  I've spent a lot of time modifying *visudo* after running into this problem and seem to be running down some rabbit holes.  If not already painfully clear, I'm new to Linux as well.

Appreciate your time.
Jim

Comment: You'll need to find a new tutorial. You're attempting to execute the ntp configuration file, which won't happen, as it doesn't contain any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was already assessed in an [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openntpd/+bug/458061) and [GitHub](https://github.com/debops/ansible-ntp/issues/10) issue request. Just a heads up in the future, a simple google search will bring up some gold results.

The best solution seems to be:

```
$ dpkg --purge ntp
$ invoke-rc.d apparmor restart
$ apt-get install openntpd
```

Comment: Thanks Braydon.  I did spend a significant amount of time googling issues,  the underline problem here clearly is user error.  I don't understand enough of what am doing to even google the issues correctly.  My NTP server is now up and running.

Comment: @yscustom It's perfectly fine! I know your issue when I first started. Sometimes google can be tricky with words to get the right result, I hope I didn't come off as rude though.

As long as you check first and can't find then post here. I'm glad your issue was fixed.